# Make HTTP SOAP request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, wcf

i would like to make post request to WCF SOAP service. currently in network view getting error "400 bad Request".
Request in variable xmls is same as in WVF test client request.

```
let xmls='<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"\
                                     <s:Header/>\
            <Action s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">http://tempuri.org/IReportsListsService/GetClients</Action>\
            </s:Header>\
            <s:Body>\
            <GetClients xmlns="http://tempuri.org/" />\
                      </s:Body>\
          </s:Envelope>';

axios.post('http://localhost:8735/ReportsListsService',
           xmls,
           {headers:
             {'Content-Type': 'text/xml',
             SOAPAction: 'http://tempuri.org/IReportsListsService/GetClients'}
           }).then(res=>{
             console.log(res);
           }).catch(err=>{console.log(err)});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seem to be a lot of places this can fail.  Are you sure the XML is valid?  Are all the necessary headers set for the api?  Axios itself is working if you are getting any kind of request back (assuming you are connected to the internet), so I'd suggest double checking everything else.

Comment: XML i was just copied from WCF test Client. Can it be same or need same changes? Headers? I also think the problem will be here, where to check which headers i need?(i have local WCF SOAP service, so i can check all source codes)